# Ornstein Uhlenbeck process get SDE back from the solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process defined as:

\begin{equation}
dX_t = k \: (\theta - X_t) dt + \lambda dW_t
\end{equation}
With $k > 0$ and $W_t$ a standard brownian motion.
Following tutorials, I use $Y_t = X_t exp(tk)$ to get to a solution:

\begin{array}
 (X_t = \theta + exp(-tk) \: (X_0 - \theta) + \lambda \: \int_0^t exp(-k(t-s)) dW_s \\
 X_t = X_0 \: exp(-tk) + \theta \: (1-exp(-tk)) + \lambda \: \int_0^t exp(-k(t-s)) dW_s \\
\end{array}

the question is: How do I get from that last expression back to the original SDE? For when I try to do the differentiation I get:

\begin{array}
(dX_t = -k\: X_0 \: exp(-tk) dt + k \: \theta \: exp(-tk) dt + \lambda \: exp(-k(t-t)) dW_t\\
dX_t = k\: exp(-tk)  (\theta - X_0)dt+ \lambda dW_t \neq k \: (\theta - X_t) dt + \lambda dW_t\\
\end{array}

Which is different from the SDE:

- There's an $exp(-tk)$
- The mean reverting term has a $X_0$ instead of a $X_t$

I think I am messing up with the way I am differentiating.

Comment: Since your $dW$-integral has a $t$ in the integrand and in the upper limit you have to apply a Leibniz rule, or pull out $\exp(-kt)$ and apply a product rule (in Ito calculus of course).

Comment: I have a doubt when applying Ito's formula. When computing the $\frac{d}{dW}$ In the term $\lambda exp(-kt) \int_0^t exp(ks) dW_s$, why and how that ends up being $\lambda dW_t$ ?

Comment: We don't compute $\frac{d}{dW}\,.$ Write $U_t=\exp(-kt)$ and $V_t=\int_0^t\exp(sk)\,dW_s$ and use the integration-by-parts formula $d(U_tV_t)=V_td\,U_t+U_t\,dV_t+d\langle U,V\rangle_t$ which is a variant of Ito's formula in 2d. Do you know why the last term vanishes?

Comment: Having $X_t = \theta+exp(-kt)(X_0-\theta)+\lambda(\int_0^t exp(-k(t-s))dW_s)$ I want $dX_t$.  $d\theta$ is 0, the 2nd term $-kexp(-kt)(X_0-\theta)$ and the third I apply what you suggest, I get $V_tdU_t = \int_0^t exp(ks))dW_s=(-k)exp(-kt)dt$; $U_t dV_t = exp(-kt)d\int_0^t exp(-k(t-s))dW_s$ and the last bracket I would say it is 0 because the $exp$ is of finite variation? 
Then we have the 'middle term' $exp(-kt)d\int_0^t exp(ks)dW_s = exp(-kt) exp(kt) dW_t$ which I am having some trouble justifying, does $d\int_0^t f(x) dW_x = f(t) dW_t - f(0) dW_0$ hold in general?

Comment: Yes, the bracket is zero and the answer to your last question is yes. Please write an answer or edit the question so that other users can learn from that.